# libGDX draw a text using a decals to 3d facing camera

Tags: java, text, 3d, libgdx, draw

I have a working code for drawing decals:
Init:

```
Decal decal = Decal.newDecal(1, 1, 
new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("2d/gui/badlogic.jpg"))) );
            decal.setPosition(10, 10, 10);
            decal.setScale(3);
            decals.add(decal);
```

Draw method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < decals.size; i++) {
        Decal decal = decals.get(i);

        decal.lookAt(stage3d.getCamera().position, stage3d.getCamera().up);

        batch.add(decal);
    }
batch.flush();
```

I have a working code for writing text in 3d:
Draw method:

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(tmpMat4.set(camera.combined).mul(textTransform));
spriteBatch.begin();
font.draw(spriteBatch, "Testing 1 2 3", 0, 0);
spriteBatch.end();
```

But I have a trouble to make a facing text.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't try the Decal method because it's not set up for text. SpriteBatch is already set up for text.

*(The Decal method could theoretically perform better because you wouldn't need a separate draw call for each string of text. However, you would have to roll your own version of BitmapFont and BitmapFontCache that is compatible with Decals. Of course, if you did that, you could submit a pull request and get it added to libgdx.)*

That SpriteBatch code looks familar. :) Basically what you need to do is modify the `textTransform` matrix to cause it to rotate an object to face the camera. SpriteBatch is set up to draw flat stuff that is facing the Z direction. So you need to rotate a Z vector to face the camera.

First you will want a Vector3 that you can reuse.

```
private static Vector3 tmpVec3 = new Vector3();
```

Then you want to find the vector that points from the center of the text to the camera. I'm assuming you are storing the text's position in 3D space in a Vector3 called `textPosition` here:

```
tmpVec3.set(camera.position).sub(textPosition); 
//tmpVec3 is now a vector pointing from the text to the camera.
```

Now you can position the object's matrix and then rotate it to face the camera like this:

```
textTransform.setToTranslation(textPosition).rotate(Vector3.Z, tmpVec3);
```

Now you can use the `textTransform` as in the code you posted. Make sure you set the BitmapFont's alignment to HAlignment.center or the text will rotate about the left end of the string of text instead of the center. You also probably want to set the `integer` parameter to false for drawing in 3D.